# keep selected item of dropdownlist as you move from page to page in a webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page that has a dropdownlist and a webgrid. The webgrid has pagenumbers. If I am on page 1 and I select page 2 the item
 selected on the dropdown is lost and goes back to "Select Branch"

I want to be able to keep the item selected as I move from page to page. How do I do that? I tried the request.form but did not work

```
         public ActionResult Index()
                {          
                    var currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();

                    Edmviewmodel objedmtest = new Edmviewmodel();

                    string ddlState_SelectedStateValue = Request.Form["ddlDropDownList"];

                    if (currentUser != null)
                    {              
                        try
                        {
                            objedmtest = _edmDataService.GetRequiredData("A05");

                            ViewData["SelectList"] = HttpContext.Session["SelectList"] ?? new List<string>();

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                            //logger.Error(ex);
                        }
                    }

                    return View(objedmtest);
                }
```

Here is the html code.

```
                @{
                var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model.GetCatDataByLocation,
                defaultSort: "CustomerName",
                canSort: true,
                rowsPerPage: 5

               );
            }


            <div>

                <div>
                    <label for="ddlBranch">Branch:</label>

                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlDropDownList", Model.BranchesSelectList, "Select Branch", new { @class = "css-class" })

                </div>
                <div>
                    @grid.GetHtml(
                tableStyle: "grid",
                headerStyle: "head",
                alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("Select", format: @<text><input name="CustomerName" type="checkbox" value="@item.CustomerName" @Html.Raw(((List<string>)ViewData["SelectList"]).Contains(@item.CustomerName) ? "checked" : "") /></text>),
                      grid.Column("CustomerName", "CustomerName"),
                      grid.Column("CustomerNumber", "CustomerNumber"),
                      grid.Column("Orderdate", "Orderdate", canSort: false),
                      grid.Column("OrderNumber", "OrderNumber"),
                      grid.Column("Routenumber", "Routenumber"),
                      grid.Column("Primaryrep", "Primaryrep"),
                      grid.Column("Isvalidated", "Isvalidated")
                       )
                     )

                </div>

                <div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //check for existance of query string 
            var urlg = window.location.href; //global url
            var previousIndex = 0;
            if (urlg.indexOf("ap") > 0) {
                previousIndex = (urlg.substring(urlg.indexOf("ap=") + 3));
            }


            $('select>option:eq(' + previousIndex + ')').prop('selected', true);  //zero-based

            $("a").click(function (event) {

                $("td a").each(function () {
                    var old = $(this).attr('href');
                    idx = $("select[name='ddlDropDownList'] option:selected").index();
                    $(this).attr("href", old + "&ap=" + idx);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: add jquery and this example thinks you are using a get instead of post